# Draw Font Awesome icons to canvas based on class names

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, font-awesome, font-face

I want to be able to:

1. Get the Font Awesome 5 unicode character for any given Font Awesome class name (`fas fa-check-circle`, etc...)
2. Draw that unicode character to an html5 canvas

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

To get the correct unicode character and other important data for a Font Awesome 5 icon class and draw it onto an html5 canvas:

```js
// create an icon with the Font Awesome class name you want
const i = document.createElement('i');

i.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-check-circle');
document.body.appendChild(i);

// get the styles for the icon you just made
const iStyles = window.getComputedStyle(i);
const iBeforeStyles = window.getComputedStyle(i, ':before');

const fontFamily = iStyles.getPropertyValue('font-family');
const fontWeight = iStyles.getPropertyValue('font-weight');
const fontSize = '40px'; // just to make things a little bigger...

const canvasFont = `${fontWeight} ${fontSize} ${fontFamily}`; // should be something like: '900 40px "Font Awesome 5 Pro"'
const icon = String.fromCodePoint(iBeforeStyles.getPropertyValue('content').codePointAt(1)); // codePointAt(1) because the first character is a double quote


const ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.font = canvasFont;
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.textAlign = 'center';
ctx.fillText(icon, myCanvas.width / 2, myCanvas.height / 2);
```

When you do this, make sure the Font Awesome 5 font has actually loaded when you do the drawing. I made the mistake of only drawing once when I was testing and it resulted in only a box showing up. When the icon has loaded it should appear like this:

[image: icon rendered in canvas]